# WARNING: yacc table file version is out of date

Tags: ply

I have the following issue in our PythonQL project:

When I'm running from Jupyter notebook, this message pops up all the time:
WARNING: yacc table file version is out of date
Generating LALR tables

However, when using from command line, this doesn't happen at all (we ship with precomputed parser files).

We're adding Jupyter support right now and would like to fix this, but have no idea where to look for a solution...

Answer (score 0):

Quite probably the Jupyter notebook and the command line use different virtual environments (or one does and the other doesn't use a virtual environment).

I have this case in a common tree between Python 2 and Python 3, where:

#### Python 3

```
>>> import ply
>>> ply.__version__
'3.11'
```

#### Python 2

```
>>> import ply
>>> ply.__version__
'3.9'
```

The `ply` version is recorded in the `parser.out` file as:

```
Created by PLY version 3.9 (http://www.dabeaz.com/ply)
```

…and on startup the other `ply` version notices the “incompatibility” and recreates the files.
You'll only have to ensure that in both cases the same version of `ply` is installed.

You could select one virtual environment, use `pip freeze >requirements.pip` and then in the other virtual environment issue a `pip install -U -r requirements.pip`, or something like it.